# Resize a dot and making that dot appear without having to write text inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem a dot on my garboard canvas. First of all, my dot does not show up until i add text to, which is weird since I set it a height and width of 100 and 40. 
I'm using codepen, which is why I know it's not a linking problem. Next, I can change the attributes 100 and 40, but the dot itself does not move, it though I assigned it the class of .man.

---

I also know that this will probably look simple yo most of you, but I'm just a kid, so I don't know too much. 
Here is my code:

```js
// calling the dice id and "listening" to when it is clicked and then running numChange
var dice = document.getElementById("dice").addEventListener("click", numChange);
// creating a function called numChange without any arguments and alerting a random number 1-6
function numChange() {
  alert(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1));
}
// slecting "man" using doc.qs and calling upon ".man"
let circle = document.getElementById("stick-man");
let moveBy = 25;
//adding a el to window and setting atrubute to "load", as well a empty () and a reference =>
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  //circle position now "absolute"
  circle.style.position = "absolute";
  //my circle is now at the top left corner
  circle.style.left = 0;
  circle.style.top = 0;
});
// checking if positition is 550 and 75, though it will change thanks to my new baord...
function verifyPosition(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition, moveBy) {
  //console.log(circleLeftPosition, circleRightPosition );
  if (circleLeftPosition == '550px' && circleRightPosition == '75px') {
    alert("Who created the internet?");
    //Something.. HAVE NO IDEA WHAT THOUGH! b
  }
}
// another ael but this time for "keyup", with e inside our (), and our => {}
window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  switch (e.key) {
    //fist case checs for left arrow
    case "ArrowLeft":
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
      //second for right arrow
    case "ArrowRight":
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.left = parseInt(circle.style.left) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowUp":
      //third for up
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) - moveBy + "px";
      break;
    case "ArrowDown":
      //fourth for down
      verifyPosition(circle.style.left, circle.style.top, moveBy);
      circle.style.top = parseInt(circle.style.top) + moveBy + "px";
      break;
  }
});

const popOpen = document.querySelectorAll('[data-popup-target]');
const popClose = document.querySelectorAll('[data-button]');
const overLay = document.getElementById('overlay');

popOpen.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = document.querySelectorAll(button.dataset.popupTarget);
    openPopup(pop);
  });
});

popClose.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = button.closest('.popup');
    closePopup(pop);
  });
});

function openPopup(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return;
  popup.classList.add('active');
  overLay.classList.add('active');
}

function closePopup(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return;
  popup.classList.remove('active');
  overLay.classList.remove('active');
}


const openErrorPop = document.querySelectorAll('[data-target]')
const closeErrorPop = document.querySelectorAll('[data-pop-close]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('pop-idOverlay')

closeErrorPop.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = button.closest('.class-pop')
    closePop(pop)
  })
})

openErrorPop.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const pop = document.querySelector(button.dataset.target)
    openPop(pop)
  })
})

function openPop(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return
  pop.classList.add('active')
  overlay.classList.add('active')
}

function closePop(pop) {
  if (pop == null) return
  pop.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}
```

```css
/* styles man  not yet working*/

.stick-man {
  cursor: pointer;
  height 100px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 16;
}


/* style button */

.open {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 340px;
}


/* makes a board for the grid so stay on */

.board {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  /*   (commented out)grid-gap: -1px; */
  left: 220px;
  top: 45px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 10vw);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 10vw);
}


/* styles all sqaures at once */

.square {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* styles sqaure 1 */

.square:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* styles sqaure 2 */

.square:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}


/* styles sqaure 3 */

.square:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
}


/* styles sqaure 4 */

.square:nth-child(4) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 4;
}


/* styles sqaure 5 */

.square:nth-child(5) {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 5;
}


/* styles sqaure 6 */

.square:nth-child(6) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 5;
}


/* styles sqaure 7 */

.square:nth-child(7) {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 5;
}


/* styles sqaure 8 */

.square:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 5;
}


/* styles sqaure 9 */

.square:nth-child(9) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 5;
}


/* styles sqaure 101 */

.square:nth-child(10) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 4;
}


/* styles sqaure 11 */

.square:nth-child(11) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 3;
}


/* styles sqaure 12 */

.square:nth-child(12) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 2;
}


/* styles sqaure 13 */

.square:nth-child(13) {
  grid-row: 5;
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* styles sqaure 14 */

.square:nth-child(14) {
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* styles sqaure 15 */

.square:nth-child(15) {
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* styles sqaure 16 */

.square:nth-child(16) {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}


/* giving padding to baord elements */

.board {
  padding: 1em 0;
}


/* cleans up by transfering more .sqaure code another call */

.square {
  background: #eaeaea;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* .man2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 410px;
  right: 545px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: up 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 8.5s;
}
.man3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  right: 545px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: black;
  animation: right2 9s infinite;
  animation-delay: 17s;
} */


/* @keyframes right {
  from {
    right: 240px;
  }
  to {
    right: 540px;
  }
  0% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  75% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
  }
} */


/* makes a dice visible and clickable */

.dice {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #AB6634;
  position: absolute;
  right: 440px;
  top: 320px;
  z-index: 9;
}


/* creates a templat for the dice, and lator on cards and text, to sit on */

.inside-board {
  position: absolute;
  height: 45%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  top: 145px;
  right: 290px;
}


/* pre-code for question number one (may be deleted) */

.q1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 440px;
  right: 200px;
}


/* changes font family to dosis for less-ugly looking text */

* {
  font-family: dosis, sans-serif;
}


/* popup code */


/* styles popupe created in HTML */

.class-pop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
}


/* makes popup appear when .active is applied to the list */

.class-pop.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}


/* styles header */

.pop-classhead {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-item: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}


/* styles the title so it stands out */

.classhead-title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* styles the button on the header */

.classhead-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  background: white;
  font-size: 1.05rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* makes the body seem less squezed into the box */

.pop-classbody {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}


/* stretches the overlay to every corner of the screen and colors it */

.pop-classoverlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: 300ms ease-in-out;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* makes it appear when .active is added to the list */

.pop-classoverlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}


/* comented out code */


/* 
.img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
}

.form {
  font-size: 1.00rem;
} */


/* td {
  background-color: #BA7A3A;
  width: 65px;
  height: 65px;
  text-align: center;
}

.noPeice {
  background-color: #F0D2B4;
} */
```

```html
<!-- title -->
<h1 class="board">STORIE</h1>
<!-- starting div's -->
<div class="stick-man" id="stick-man">/. / </div>
<div class="dice" id="dice"></div>
<div class="inside-board"></div>
<!-- baord element -->
<div class="board">
  <!--   start square -->
  <div class="square">START
    <!--     opening button -->
    <button class="open" data-target="#id-pop">
    I
  </button>
    <!--     popup head parent -->
    <div class="class-pop" id="id-pop">
      <!--     popup head -->
      <div class="pop-classhead" id="pop-idHead">
        <div class="classhead-title" data-id-Head-title>Info Card #1</div>
        <button data-pop-close class="classhead-close" id="idHead-close">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <!--     popup body -->
      <div class="pop-classbody" data-pop-idBody>
        Bob Khan and Vint Cerf created internet in the 1900's. Eventually, the internet, then called the E-ternet became public. For more information, visite <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet">This wikipedia page</a><br>
        <!--       form elment for checkbox -->
        <form>Did you click the link?
          <inb put type="checkbox">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--     gray overylay -->
    <div class="pop-classoverlay" id="pop-idOverlay"></div>

  </div>
  <!--   inactive sqaures -->
  <!--   garduin sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">guardian</div>
  <!--   blank square parent div -->
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   garduin sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">LAVA</div>
  <!--    LAVA sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">NATIVE</div>
  <!--   NATIVE blank parent div -->
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">wizard</div>
  <!--   wizard sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">king</div>
  <!--   king sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">bank</div>
  <!--   bank sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">EARTH</div>
  <!--   EARTH sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">guardian</div>
  <!--   garduin sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
  <div class="square">blank</div>
  <!--   blank sqaure parent div -->
</div>
<!-- code for later -->
<!--   <div class="q1" id="q1">
    <ul>
      <li>Who created the internet?</li>
      <li><a heref="#">Bob Khan</a></li>
      <li><a heref="#">Vint Cerf</a></li>
      <li><a heref="#">Both Bob Khan and Vint Cerf</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
  </div>
  </div> -->

<!--   <table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="noPeice"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.stick-man {
    cursor: pointer;
    /* height 100px: */
    /* width: 40px; */
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 16;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    margin: 150px;
}
```

remove height and width, assign min-width and min-height as per your requirement, you can also use margin at this class to shift as per your need, let me know if things are still unclear.
dont forget to upvote if it solves your query.

Comment: Thanks for trying you best, @Seema. Here is the link to my codepen: [https://codepen.io/Dims09/pen/qBqLbez?editors=0010]

Comment: Thank you @Seema, Your solution did not work. I am figuring that out as well. Anyways, thank you for trying your best. Dimitri

Comment: could you please explain your query bit more.

Comment: The only query I can think of querySlector();. I use querySelector to call upon my data elements, which therefor could be called upon as my target, parent element, and close button. If this is the wrong, please specify the "query" your are asking about.